# Add a day with selected date using Jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been trying to add a day for another date field with date selected of current field

```
     ,
 onSelect: function(date) {
     var date2 = $('.currDate').datepicker('getDate');
       date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1); 
       $('.nextDt').datepicker('setDate', date2);
    }
```

However I am getting at `date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);`

```
Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because, `currDate` might be empty.

If `currDate` is emtpy `$('.currDate').datepicker('getDate')` will return `null` in which case   `date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);` could throw the error

Update:

```
$(function() {
    $('#nxtDate').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
    });
    $("#currDate").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy", 
        minDate:  0,
        onSelect: function(date){
            var date2 = $('#currDate').datepicker('getDate');
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+1);
            $('#nxtDate').datepicker('setDate', date2);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Arun When I am using `$('.currDate').datepicker('getDate')` I am getting alert as `[object object]` and if I am using `var date2 = date; 
         alert(date2);` gives me `21-Apr-2013`

Comment: @Polppan is the `onSelect` registered for `currDate` picker

Comment: @Polppan I've [this demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dHEynVvqZ4fi7JrsrCHD?p=preview), can you recreate the issue

Comment: Arun, I have modified [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/dHEynVvqZ4fi7JrsrCHD?p=preview) with my version of JS files, same error occurs. Is it something to do with my JS file versions? I wouldn't be able to upgrade to latest files though

Comment: @Polppan your changes are not reflected in the file, please  clone the demo and save it after making the changes

Comment: @Polppan there is no field `closingDate`

Comment: @Polppan your input field has `id` not `class` so change the selector `$(".currDate")` to `$("#currDate")` in your `onSelect` method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28549/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-polppan)

Answer (score 2):

`setDate` and `getDate` are the functions supported by `Date()` of js while you getDate from datepicker it returns as string so you need to convert it or try this code:

```
onSelect: function(date) {  
     if(date!=undefined){
         var dateObject=new Date(date);
         dateObject.setDate(dateObject.getDate()+1);                                 
         $('.nextDt').datepicker('setDate', dateObject);
      }
    }
```

Here is [Demo Alerting Current and Next Date](http://jsfiddle.net/GHKRS/7/)

Answer (score -3):

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+".$nod." days"));
```

nod= Number of days

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!