# jqueryui datepicker - maintain offset between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, datepicker

I am using the jqueryui datepicker (http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range) to select a range for scheduling an event. I am attempting to maintain the offset between the two dates when the start date is changed. I was able to find a reasonable solution in another post ([Add a day with selected date using Jquery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117718/add-a-day-with-selected-date-using-jquery-datepicker)) but I found that when you pick a date that is before the currently selected start date (Example: change the start date from 10/20/2013 to 10/13/2013) it returns the last date that was selected instead of the offset date.

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#date_start" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  showOn: "both",
  buttonImage: "images/smCal.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  constrainInput: true,
  onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
      var stDate = $( "#curStartDate" ).val().split('-');
      var enDate = $( "#date_end" ).val().split('-');

      var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
      var firstDate = new Date(stDate[0],stDate[1],stDate[2]);
      var secondDate = new Date(enDate[0],enDate[1],enDate[2]);

      var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((firstDate.getTime() - secondDate.getTime())/(oneDay)));

      if(!isNumber(diffDays)) {
        diffDays = 0;  
      }

      var date2 = $('#date_start').datepicker('getDate');
      date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+diffDays);

      $('#date_end').datepicker('setDate', date2);
     $( "#curStartDate" ).val(selectedDate)
     $( "#date_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
  }
});

$( "#date_end" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  numberOfMonths: 1,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  showOn: "both",
  buttonImage: "images/smCal.gif",
  buttonImageOnly: true,
  constrainInput: true,
  minDate:$( "#date_start" ).val()
});

$( "#curStartDate" ).val($( "#date_start" ).val());
 });
 function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. I had the minDate set for the #date_end value to the current value of the #date_start. So it was auto correcting the date selection to the latest available date that was the last selected date in #date_start. So to fix the issue I simply change the minDate before attempting to change the #date_end.

New Code:

```
<script>
$(function() {

  $( "#date_start" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/smCal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
  constrainInput: true,
    onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
      var diffDays = daydiff(parseDate($('#curStartDate').val()), parseDate($('#date_end').val()));

      if(!isNumber(diffDays)) diffDays = 0; 

      var date2 = $('#date_start').datepicker('getDate');
      date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+diffDays);

      $( "#date_end" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      $('#date_end').datepicker('setDate', date2);
     $( "#curStartDate" ).val(selectedDate)
    }
  });

  $( "#date_end" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
  showOn: "both",
    buttonImage: "images/smCal.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
  constrainInput: true,
  minDate:$( "#date_start" ).val()
  });

$( "#curStartDate" ).val($( "#date_start" ).val());
});

function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
function parseDate(str) {
  var mdy = str.split('-');
  return new Date(mdy[0], mdy[1]-1, mdy[2]);
}
function daydiff(first, second) {
  return (second-first)/(1000*60*60*24);
}
</script>
```