# Date picker textbox change adding months to next textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my Asp.Net mvc webapplication, I have a scenario where there are 2 date picker text boxes. From first Text box I pick one date(jquery ui calender picker). On selecting date and move out of text box...the next text box should show date + 48 months in it. How to achieve with jquery.

```
// first Textbox where i pick one date for jquery ui calender picker. On selecting and move out of text box below textbox should get selected date + 48 months with jquery

 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { @Value = @Model.ReleaseDate == null ? "" : string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", @Model.ReleaseDate), @id = "releaseDate" })

//Second textbox
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @Value = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", @Model.EndDate ?? DateTime.Now.AddMonths(48)), @id = "endDate" })
```

Comment: Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117718/add-a-day-with-selected-date-using-jquery-datepicker

Answer (score 1):

From the top of my head, please recheck the syntax

You will need Javascript for that:

```
var sdate = $('#ReleaseDate').val();
var current = new Date(sdate);
current.setMonth(CurrentDate.getMonth()+48);
```

and then set the end date:

```
$('#EndDate').val(current.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. Below is the fix

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chandrashekarthota/AncD2/1/)

```
<input type="text" class="firstcal">
<input type="text" class="secondcal">

$(function() {
    $(".firstcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 48);
            $(".secondcal").datepicker("setDate", date);
        }
    });
    $(".secondcal").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    });
});
```